# Accessing child property from Parent class in php

Tags: java, php, oop, visibility

I come from java background and recently testing some OOP methodology in PHP. I found that it is permitted for a parent class to use Child class property. The code below describes what I am trying to say.

```
<?php
    class ParentClass {
        public static function test() {
            echo "hello world ". implode(',', static::$prop);
        }
    }

    class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
        public static $prop = ['a' , 'b'];
    }

ChildClass::test();

?>
```

On the above code, the ParentClass is using the $prop variable from its function `test()` . This simply outputs with no error. However, it is not permissible in Java. What is the reason behind this methodology in PHP?

Answer (score 2):

Java doesn't have the concept of [Late static bindings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php):

> "Late binding" comes from the fact that static:: will not be resolved using the class where the method is defined but it will rather be computed using runtime information.

If you use `self::` you'll have the behaviour as you know it from Java. However `static::` resolves at runtime.